# xsl wont work at all

Tags: xml, xslt

Sorry if this looks ridiculous I'm really trying here but am not grasping this xml class I am in. Please take a look and point me in the right direction, or if you could at least take me out of the deep end

Here is the xml portion

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sci.xsl" ?>
<rss version="2.0"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"

                    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"

                    xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/"

                    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">



<channel>
   <title>SciTimes News</title>
   <link>home.htm</link>

   <description>SciTimes delivers up-to-the-minute news and information on
   the latest stories from the world of science and technology.</description>

   <dc:language>en-us</dc:language>

<dc:date>2008-03-24T12:22:54+09:00</dc:date>

<sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>

   <sy:updateFrequency>1</sy:updateFrequency>

   <sy:updateBase>2000-01-01T12:00+00:00</sy:updateBase>


   <image>
      <title>SciTimes.com</title>
      <link>home.htm</link>
      <url>scitimes.jpg</url>
      <width>620</width>
      <height>96</height>
      <description>SciTimes delivers up-to-the-minute news and information on
      the latest stories from the world of science and technology.
      </description>
   </image>

   <item>
      <title>Visual Memory</title>
      <link>vm.htm</link>
      <description>BOULDER, Colorado - The ability to retain memory about the 
      details of a natural scene is unaffected by the distraction of another 
      activity and this information is retained in "working memory" according 
      to researchers at the University of Colorado School of Medicine. These 
      results reinforce the notion that humans maintain useful information about 
      previous fixations in long-term working memory rather than the 
      limited capacity of visual short-term memory (VSTM). 
      </description>
      <dc:pubDate>Mon, 24 Mar 2008 12:17:37 EST</dc:pubDate>
      <dc:subject>Biology</dc:subject>

   </item>

   <item>
      <title>Neptune probe launches</title>
      <link>neptune.htm</link>
      <description>CAPE CANAVERAL, Florida - The fastest spacecraft ever launched 
      began the first full day of its 2-billion mile journey to Neptune, where it 
      will study the gas giant and provide close-up images of its rings. The Neptune 5 
      spacecraft blasted off aboard an Atlas V rocket Sunday evening in a spectacular 
      start to the $900 million mission. The spacecraft can reach 38,000 mph, taking 6 
      years to reach Neptune and the outer reaches of the Solar System.
      </description>
      <dc:pubDate>Mon, 24 Mar 2008 12:11:44 EST</dc:pubDate>
      <dc:subject>Space</dc:subject>

   </item>

   <item>
      <title>Whale numbers in decline</title>
      <link>whales.htm</link>
      <description>ANCHORAGE, Alaska - A survey of beluga whales in Cook Inlet finds 
      that their numbers remain stagnant and could be declining despite efforts to get 
      the white whale population to rebound. Biologists with the NOAA conducted an aerial 
      survey southwest of Anchorage early last summer to count the belugas. An analysis 
      of the survey data indicates there were an estimated 324 beluga whales in Cook Inlet 
      in 2007, down from 376 the year before.
      </description>
      <dc:pubDate>Mon, 24 Mar 2008 12:05:12 EST</dc:pubDate>
      <dc:subject>Biology</dc:subject>

   </item>

   <item>
      <title>Satellite goes silent</title>
      <link>nasa.htm</link>
      <description>LOS ANGELES, California - A NASA satellite studying the Earth's Van 
      Allen Belt has stopped operating after three years, the space agency announced 
      over the weekend. The satellite, launched in 2004, successfully completed its 
      two-year primary mission, according to a NASA news release. It made observations 
      until last month when engineers discovered that its power supply had failed.
      </description>
      <dc:pubDate>Mon, 24 Mar 2008 12:03:31 EST</dc:pubDate>
      <dc:subject>Space</dc:subject>

   </item>

</channel>
</rss>
```

here is the XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl= "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:rss="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/" version="1.0"
        xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
        exclude-result-prefixes="rss dc">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title><xsl:value-of select="channel/title"/></title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="sci.css" type="text/css"/>
        </head>
        <body>      
        <div id="logo"><xsl:apply-templates select="image"/></div>
        <div id="datetime"><xsl:value-of select="./dc:date"/>date</div>

        <div id="links">
            <p><xsl:apply-templates select="description"/></p>
            description
            <p><img src="links.jpg"/></p>
        </div>
        <div id="news">
            <h1>RSS News Feed</h1>
            items
        </div>
        </body>
    </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="image">
    <a href="{../link}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </a>
        <img src="{./url}" alt="{./title}" width="{./width}"
        height="{./height}" longdesc="{./description}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></img>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="dc:date">
        <xsl:value-of select="/dc:date"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="description">
        <xsl:value-of select="/channel/description"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output that I am getting is just what is in the "Date, description, RSS news feeds and items in the body section thats it! please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us what you're expecting for output.

Comment: It is supposed to be a news reader but none of the, content from the xml is being produced just the styles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several mistakes. The basic mistake is that you incorrectly evoke templates.
Example:

```
    //you need to indicate path to the node
<xsl:apply-templates select="channel/description"/>
```

I've fixed some of those, try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl= "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:rss="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/" version="1.0"
        xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
        exclude-result-prefixes="rss dc">
  <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0"/>

  <xsl:template match="rss">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>
          <xsl:value-of select="channel/title"/>
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="sci.css" type="text/css"/>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="logo">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="channel/image"/>
        </div>
        <div id="datetime">
          <xsl:value-of select="channel/dc:date"/>date
        </div>

        <div id="links">
          <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="channel/description"/>
          </p>
          description
          <p>
            <img src="links.jpg"/>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div id="news">
          <h1>RSS News Feed</h1>
          items
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="image">
    <a href="{../link}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </a>
    <img src="{./url}" alt="{./title}" width="{./width}"
    height="{./height}" longdesc="{./description}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </img>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="dc:date">
    <xsl:value-of select="/dc:date"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="description">
    <xsl:value-of select="channel/description"/> lalala TEMPLATE!
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thats a start its finally recognizing some of the xml content that it was not before.

Comment: You can move forward now and update your question when stuck again.

Comment: why did changing the template xpath from  <xsl:template match="/"> to  <xsl:template match="rss"> make such a difference? and what does the "rss" refer to? I though that applying it to the whole root node is the proper way.

Comment: / - refers to the root. You can use it, but you'll be forced to use longer paths in your templates. Example that will work with /: <xsl:apply-templates select="rss/channel/description"/>